# IOS Swift Google Maps Api How to stop use storyboard and change to use Automatic Reference Counting

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to learn how to create Google Map on iPhone. I followed the steps of GoogleMaps Guide. But in step 6, I really don't know `create a new Single View Application; disabling Use Storyboards but enabling Use Automatic Reference Counting (ARC).`[Step 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOdEH.png) What is this mean?

Apart from step 6, I finish all the step. But When I run project, the map doesn't display on phone. So I guess it's wrong because I didn't complete step 6

How should I do the step 6?

Comment: I don't know what is the problem in this question to be voted down

Answer (score 1):

That guide is a bit outdated. I think the options "Use Storyboards" and `Use Automatic Reference Counting` don't exist any more in the new project dialog in newer Xcode versions.

Whenever you create a new swift project, it will always use storyboards and use ARC. Step 6 tells you to disable storyboards but I don't think it matters (according to my own experience). The important thing here is to have this code in your View Controller's `viewDidLoad` method, not the `loadView` method:

```
let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: -33.86, longitude: 151.20, zoom: 6.0)
let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
view = mapView
```

Comment: Alright. That why I google and don't get any answer.

Answer (score 1):

At first I also faced the same problem, when I run the app, it crashed. Later I created a brand new simple app and again follow every steps in **"Getting Started (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start)"** except **"disabling Use Storyboards but enabling Use Automatic Reference Counting (ARC)"** because its not applicable for latest version of Xcode and finally it worked.

After this successful map view, I do some changes. Here I placed codes in both methods(loadView() and viewDidLoad()) once at a time. Map is working fine from both methods.

At first my mistake was, instead of UIViewController.view property(root view of this view controller), I took another UIView in storyboard and later I assign GMSMapView object into that view. It makes app crash(black screen) if you do this in loadView() method.